# backbone.js router route not trigger for the first time

Tags: backbone.js

I am using backbone 1.1.2, my router:

```
    var App = Backbone.Router.extend({

        views : {},

        routes : {
            "profile" : "profile",
            "members" : "members",
            "member/:id" : "loadMember",
            'invite' : 'invite',


        },

...... my handlers
```

and the router init code:

```
var app = new FW.Daily.App();
Backbone.history.start();
Backbone.history.loadUrl(Backbone.history.fragment);
```

when some one click an url like "www.domain.com/#profile" on mobile ( tried on android 4.2 and iphone 4 & 5), SOMETIMES the handler function does not call for the first time, only when opening the page one more time, it works and the subsequence page view works fine.

Desktop browsers do not have this problems so far (tried on ie 9 - 10, firefox, chrome, opera)

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why `loadUrl` instead `navigate`

Comment: because i want to force trigger the handler, "navigate" only trigger the handler only when "fragment" is changed.